# keyboard doesn't move the view

Tags: objective-c, ios, textfield

I am trying to write some code to make the view move up when I tap on the textfield and the keyboard appears. The view, that contains the textfield, is not the first one to appear when the program starts.
So I've written some code in the ViewController

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
 }

-(void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification*)notification {
   NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];
   NSValue* value = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
   CGSize keyboardSize = [value CGRectValue].size;

   gm.frame = CGRectMake(gm.frame.origin.x, gm.frame.origin.y, gm.frame.size.width, gm.frame.size.height-keyboardSize.height);
}

-(void)keyboarDidHide:(NSNotification*)notification {
   gm.frame = CGRectMake(gm.frame.origin.x, gm.frame.origin.y, gm.frame.size.width, gm.frame.size.height);
}
```

gm is the view that contains the textfield:

```
@class gameOverMenu;

@interface RootViewController : UIViewController {
    gameOverMenu* gm;
}
@end
```

So when I tap on the textfield these methods the program goes through these methods but nothing happens, I mean the view isn't move by keyboard and I cannot make the keyboard disappear. Why so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want it to move up or change the size?  Does this work?

```
-(void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification*)notification {
   NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];
   NSValue* value = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
   CGSize keyboardSize = [value CGRectValue].size;

   gm.frame = CGRectMake(gm.frame.origin.x, gm.frame.origin.y-keyboardSize.height, gm.frame.size.width, gm.frame.size.height);
}

-(void)keyboarDidHide:(NSNotification*)notification {
   NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];
   NSValue* value = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
   CGSize keyboardSize = [value CGRectValue].size;

   gm.frame = CGRectMake(gm.frame.origin.x, gm.frame.origin.y+keyboardSize.height, gm.frame.size.width, gm.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: I want to move it up, 
no it doesn't

Comment: log the frame before and after you change it.

Comment: what do you mean "log the frame"?

Comment: NSLog ("%@", NSStringFromCGRect(gm.frame));

Comment: funny thing {{0, 0} {0, 0}} both

Comment: yeah, that is strange.  try logging the value of its superview now.  NSLog("%@", gm.superView);  And does gm contain the textfield you are trying to move?  try adding NSLog("%d", [gm.subviews count]);

Comment: superview (null)  subviews 0. Do I adress to the view in a wrong way in RootViewController.h?

Comment: yeah, it looks like your view hierarchy is messed up.  Did you build it programmatically or with interface builder?  How do you add the textfield?  Where do you add the gm view?

Comment: I built it programmatically, Well I got the main menu of the program made by cocos2d class CCScene, when I tap on the play the UIView class  is "addChild" with the help of CCUIViewWrapper, and when the game is lost, gm view is sub viewed
    UITextField* tf;= [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 350, 150, 20)];
            [tf setPlaceholder:@"Type your name.."];
            [self addSubview:tf];

Comment: What class is this code in:  [self addSubview:tf];? gameOverMenu?

Comment: there is CCScene -> UIView -> UIView (the gm one)
so in the second UIView I add the textfield [self addSubview:tf];    and I want to make the keyboard move the view up and then to make the keyboard disappear  Yes

Comment: And how do you create and add the second UIView (the gm one)?

Comment: gameOverMenu* gorm = [[gameOverMenu alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 520)];
            gorm.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backGround.jpg"]];
            [self addSubview:gorm];

Comment: may be that mess is because of the usage of CCScene class?  the class object? in RootViewController.h

Comment: The hierarchy is not right, but it's hard to help determine what's wrong without seeing all the code.  It looks like the view you actually want to resize is gorm.  And gm is nowhere in the view hierarchy, so resizing it isn't going to do anything.  Where is this code? gameOverMenu* gorm = [[gameOverMenu alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 520)];

Comment: in the first UIView and how can I get access to it from RootViewController?

Comment: and how do you initialize RootViewController?  what are you doing in loadView for that view controller?

Comment: I do nothing in loadView, in RootViewController I have only viewDidLoad implemented, cocos2d is doing some stuff in AppDelegate in - (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application; method and I added there [viewController viewDidLoad];
line.

Comment: that is gonna to be the problem even if I make all my classes UIView

Answer (score 0):

Try using `bounds` instead of `frame`. The anchoring might be getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

this code work for me:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSValue* value = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
    CGSize keyboardSize = [value CGRectValue].size;

    webView.frame = CGRectMake(webView.frame.origin.x, webView.frame.origin.y, webView.frame.size.width, webView.frame.size.height-keyboardSize.height);
}

-(void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSValue* value = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
    CGSize keyboardSize = [value CGRectValue].size;

    webView.frame = CGRectMake(webView.frame.origin.x, webView.frame.origin.y, webView.frame.size.width, webView.frame.size.height+keyboardSize.height);
}
```